# Trouble with file upload to database (backend)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to upload files to my database but I'm having trouble.

When I try to upload a file to my database I got this error :
`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

And the data from my file is not save to my database (see the image) :
[image]

I think my problem is here :

```
  const fileData = {
    type: req.body.type,
    name: req.body.name,
    data: req.body.data
  };
```

I tried to copy the function I use for create a user when he register but for a file when someone upload it.

**Register (it works) :**

```
users.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const today = new Date();
  const userData = {
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    deliveryAddress: req.body.deliveryAddress,
    created: today
  };

  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  })
    //TODO bcrypt
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          userData.password = hash;
          User.create(userData)
            .then(user => {
              res.json({ status: user.email + " registered!" });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              res.send("error: " + err);
            });
        });
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "Email already taken" });
        console.log("Email already taken !");
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json("Error : " + err);
    });
});
```

**File upload (not working) :**

```
app.post("/files", (req, res) => {
  const uploadFile = req.files.file;
  const fileName = req.files.file.name;
  const fileData = {
    type: req.body.type,
    name: req.body.name,
    data: req.body.data
  };
  uploadFile.mv(`./uploads/${fileName}`, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    res.json({
      file: `uploads/${fileName}`
    });
  });
  Upload.findOne({
    where: {
      name: req.body.name
    }
  })
    .then(file => {
      if (!file) {
        Upload.create(fileData)
          .then(file => {
            res.json({ status: file.name + " created !" });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            res.send("error: " + err);
          });
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "File already uploaded" });
        console.log("File already uploaded");
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json("Error : " + err);
    });
});
```

I'm not very familiar with backend so...
I tried to change :

```
  const fileData = {
    type: req.body.type,
    name: req.body.name,
    data: req.body.data
  };
```

with

```
  const fileData = {
    type: req.files.file.type,
    name: req.files.file.name,
    data: req.files.file.data
  };
```

But I got an infinite loop and the file is not uploaded to my database (nothing is created).

The upload to the backend (uploads folder) works.

**EDIT**

When I use `req.files.file.something` for the fileData it works sometimes, the file is correctly uploaded to database but I got the error again (I think it works when the file is very tiny).

**For a 1 Ko file :**

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `files` (`id`,`name`,`data`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'a suprimer.html',X'3c21444f43545950452068746d6c3e0d0a0d0a3c21444f43545950452068746d6c3e0d0a3c68746d6c3e0d0a3c686561643e200d0a093c6d65746120636861727365743d227574662d38223e0d0a093c7469746c653e20466169726520756e6520696d6167653c2f7469746c653e0d0a3c2f686561643e0d0a3c626f64793e0d0a0d0a093c703e746573743c2f703e0d0a0d0a093c696d67207372633d2268642e696d6167652e736e6f772e6a706567223e0d0a090d0a0d0a3c2f626f64793e0d0a3c2f68746d6c3e','2020-01-29 10:07:28','2020-01-29 10:07:28');
```

And in the database :
[image]

Why the type is not set up ?
How can I reduce the time of the upload for a bigger file ?

Comment: Try to add `return` before your `res`.

Comment: Before `res.json({ status: file.name + " created !" });` ?

Comment: Try to add it in each `res` you have.

Comment: I have to return nothing ?

Comment: You have a `res` in your code right? only add return before your `res`. So, your code will looks like this for an example: `return res.status(200).send(yourdata);`

Comment: Nothing has changed

Comment: You can see in this method `uploadFile.mv`, after you send respond to the client, it's still run to next step. Run to this method `Upload.findOne`.

Comment: Nothing has changed and I got always the same error. See my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206845/discussion-between-titus-sutio-fanpula-and-leyh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code below:

```
app.post("/files", (req, res) => {
  const uploadFile = req.files.file;
  const fileName = req.files.file.name;
  const fileData = {
    type: req.body.type,
    name: req.body.name,
    data: req.body.data
  };
  Upload.findOne({
    where: {
      name: req.body.name
    }
  }).then(file => {
      if (!file) {
        // upload file to directory
        uploadFile.mv(`./uploads/${fileName}`);
        // save file to database
        Upload.create(fileData)
          .then(file => {
            return res.json({ status: file.name + " created !" });
          }).catch(err => {
            return res.send("error: " + err);
          });
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "File already uploaded" });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(400).json("Error : " + err);
    });
});
```

I hope it can help you to upload your file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are trying to send two responses in the same call handler. Once in `uploadfile.mv` then again in `Upload.findOne`. You cannot return two `res.X` to the same request.

This thread might be useful: [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)